# same app, different interface

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, modern-ui

I'm writing a WPF Application with [`ModernUI`](https://mui.codeplex.com/%E2%80%8E). It looks great on my computer(win 7).

[image]

However, it looks different on my colleague's(also win 7).

[image]

What can I do to make it look always like the same way, just as on my computer?

Comment: These don't look like the same styles, nor something which would be effected through system theming.  I would use Snoop or similar to find out why different styles are being used.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for your advice. I'm new in wpf. You show me a way to find it out. We'll see later.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the reason why the implicit style didn't work.

I'm using ModernUI with WPF4.0 and I deleted the

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}"/>
```

in app.xaml the other day.

Well, it's that simple and everything looks fine now. Except that I still don't know how the empty style works.

Comment: It overwrites the default `Rectangle` style. The margins, border colors,... etc are overwritten with nothing. So if the default has a margin of 4, then with your empty style it has a margin of 0. The same with all the colors.

Comment: @Loetn Yes, for sure. But how can you explain the issue I posted at the beginning.